# Sending HTML tables to C# code on server using Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have an array filled with JQuery objects that represent tables. Each index of the array is a new table basically. What I need to do is basically send each of these tables to code lying on the server that uses C#. I don't have much experience with AJAX or even JSON. I have gotten my code to call a method on the server which just returns a string saying it was reached.

How do I go about putting these HTML tables into JSON format and sending them to the server using AJAX.

This is what I have so far, it just sends back a string to verify that I reached the server.

This is an example of what a table would look like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my javascript

```
var tables: Array<JQuery> = this.BuildTables(); // Returns the 5 tables put into an array
// Call server
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //datatype: "JSON",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: true,
    url: GetHelper().GetVirtualDirectoryUrl() + "Index/GenerateExcelReport"
}).done((data) => {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function () {
    console.log('Failed to send');
});
```

This is my C# code

```
public String CreateExcelSheet()
{
    var text = "String Changed!";
    return text;
}
```

This outputs, `String Changed!`

How do I repeat this process, but pass in those HTML tables. Preferably just pass in `tables` because it contains all of them. How would I read them from inside the method when they reach the server side code?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the json?

Comment: Are you just trying to generate an excel report, or do you want the data actually bound to a model?

Comment: It would really help knowing what you are trying to send looks like

Comment: I didn't try to send anything so far. I have no idea how to make up the json to store the tables. They are just basic html tables

Comment: The ultimate goal is to create an excel report. @johnny5

Comment: Does ```this.BuildTables()``` just return a string representation of the html?

Comment: @jimenemex is this suppose to only include the current page you're on or do you need a full report?

Comment: Chances are you don't need to send the data what so ever, you just need to call the action that populates it and use that filter to create the report

Comment: @Wamadahama this.BuildTables() returns an array of JQuery Object at each index. The JQuery Object at each index is what holds the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the JSON that you generate with `this.BuildTables()` with 
var tables: Array = this.BuildTables(); // Returns the 5 tables put into an array

```
// Call server
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {tables: tables},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: true,
    url: GetHelper().GetVirtualDirectoryUrl() + "Index/GenerateExcelReport"
}).done((data) => {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function () {
    console.log('Failed to send');
});
```

note the `data: {tables: tables},` line. This will pass a json representation of the array.

One alternative is to use

```
JSON.stringify(tables)
```

Instead of putting tables in an object.

Comment: Since he says this is an array of JQuery objects, won't this contain an absurd amount of unnecessary information?